# Cloud Armor Rate-Limiting Pricing

Tags: google-cloud-platform, rate-limiting, google-cloud-armor

For Google's Cloud Armor service, does it cost to use its rate-limiting functionality, specifically on a per-request basis?

https://cloud.google.com/armor/pricing

I'm reasonably confident that it will, at minimum, cost $5 per month for the policy itself as the technical term for this is a "WAF security policy", but would the "$0.75 per million requests" apply here?

I feel their pricing page is not giving me enough information on this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will pay for three price points for Standard Tier:

- Security Policy
- Each rule that you create or enable
- Per million requests

To use Cloud Armor, you first create a security policy. Then add/create rules. This is your base cost. For one rule the current price is $5.00 + $1.00 per month. I typically create/enable about 10 rules ($5.00 + 10 * $1.00 = $15.00 per month).

Then for every million requests processed by Cloud Armor, you will pay another $0.75.